# Перевод числа в другую систему счисления

Tags: python, linux, bash, hex

Понадобилось перевести адреса IDE контроллера в десятичную систему счисления.

Пытался сделать это на Bash и на Python.
На Python хотел написать скрипт, который просто выводит на экран десятичную форму 16-ричного числа:

```
import sys
print int(sys.argv[1], '16')
```

Но на вход подается строка, которую никак не перевести в `int`, если она в 16-ричной записи.

Как это обойти?
Какую языковую конструкцию на Bash'е можно использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Можно вместо имени аргумента, сам аргумент показать

Comment: Конечно не перевести. `int` принимает вторым аргументом число, а не строку. Попробуйте `int('0xdeadbeef', 16)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш скрипт на Python не переводит, потому что фнукция `int` принимает вторым аргументом целое число. Вы можете переписать его следующим образом:

```
import sys
print(int(sys.argv[1], 16))
#         Нет кавычек  ^^
```

Вывод:

```
$ python3 ./main.py 0xdeadbeef
3735928559
```

Вариант на Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $((16#$1))
```

Аналогичный вопрос на SO: [Hexadecimal To Decimal in Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280131/hexadecimal-to-decimal-in-shell-script)

Comment: ~> python hex.py 0xd2f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hex.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(int(sys.argv[1], '16'))
TypeError: an integer is required, посмотрите вопрос получше

Comment: bash решение верно, только вот почему то раньше не работало, возможно из за пробелов мжду скобками и выражением

Comment: остается вопрос с python решением

Comment: Прочтите еще раз ответ, я объяснил, почему не работает Ваше решение.

Comment: Извените, ваш ответ верный, спасибо.

Comment: @OlegUP: следует подчеркнуть, что `'16'`  (строка) и `16` (целое число) это совершенно разные объекты, которые нельзя в перемешку использовать в большинстве случаев в Питоне. `int()` ожидает именно целое число, чтобы указать систему исчисления.

Comment: @jfs,  Дело в том, что мне казалось что int не может считывать шеснадцатиричное число заданного строкой, вот поэтму и возник вопрос.

Comment: @OlegUP: `help(int)` явно говорит, что допустимые значения для `base`: `0`, `2-36`, например, `int('xy', 35)`. Кстати, если указывать основание явно (`base=16`), то не обязательно `0x` добавлять.